# Xcode Server Bot, ipatool error

Tags: xcode7

We have an Xcode Server bot set up for CI for our project, using Xcode 7.1. It's set to produce an IPA. We only recently noticed, but a few weeks ago, it started giving this warning every build:

> Bot Issue for CareConsult Bot (develop) (build service warning)
>   Assertion: exportArchive: ipatool failed with an exception:
>
> File: (null):(null)

This prevents it from producing an IPA, which is a problem.

I've tried:
- Creating a new bot
- updating gems (saw a similar issue that was resolved this way)

Doing an archive & export on my local machine gives the same error if I choose to "Export for specific device". So the problem is not specific to the build server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Figured out that this started with 7.0.1. Xcode 7.0 exports the ipa fine.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that this has to do with enabling bit code, and the build bot is using the "compile from bitcode" option by default.  I'm still digging into this, but figured I'd share what I have found thus far.